# Convert a string to date

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used to convert a french date `23 décembre 2015 15:03` to Date.

It worked for a while. and now it doesn't work, any idea ????

```
var date = new Date('23 décembre 2015 15:03');
console.log(date);
```

> Invalid Date

Comment: [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) `A string representing an [RFC2822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.3) or ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *only* date/time format that the specification requires the `Date` constructor (or `Date.parse`, or anything else) to support is a [subset/simplification of ISO-8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format). Your string is not in that format.

To parse it, you need to either do it in your own code, or use a library like MomentJS (with, in your case, the French locale plugin).

Doing it in your own code isn't hard if that format is reliable:

```js
var months = [
  "janvier",
  "février",
  "mars",
  "avril",
  "mai",
  "juin",
  "août",
  "septembre",
  "octobre",
  "novembre",
  "décembre"
];

function parseThatDate(str) {
  var parts = /(\d{1,2}) ([^ ]+) (\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2})/.exec(str);
  if (!parts) {
    return new Date(NaN);
  }
  var month = months.indexOf(parts[2].toLowerCase());
  if (month == -1) {
    return new Date(NaN);
  }
  return new Date(+parts[3], // Year
    month, // Month
    +parts[1], // Day
    +parts[4], // Hour
    +parts[5] // Minute
  );
}

var str = "23 décembre 2015 15:03";
document.body.innerHTML = parseThatDate(str).toString();
```